# On Windows, when using Python's subprocess to run 7-Zip, the terminal can not output the compression progress

Tags: python, windows, 7zip

In a Windows system, when using Python's subprocess to run 7z.exe, the terminal does not display the compression progress. However, when I run the command directly in the Command Prompt (CMD), I can see the progress,tips:the process is Percentage progress,image as follow.

[image: Percentage progress]

i alse test comand "ping 192.168.0.1" ,I can get real-time output in the console.

```
import subprocess

command =r'E:\7-Zip\7z.exe a ArchiveName.7z D:\my7zip_test'
command1 = r'ping 192.168.0.1'

# Use subprocess.Popen to run the command and capture the output
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, shell=True, universal_newlines=True)

# Read and print the output while the process is running
while True:
    output = process.stdout.readline()
    if output == '' and process.poll() is not None:
        break
    if output:
        print(output.strip())

# Get the return code of the process
return_code = process.returncode

if return_code == 0:
    print("Compression completed successfully.")
else:
    print(f"Compression failed with return code {return_code}")
```

Who knows why and how to do it?

Comment: Is 7zip writing to stout or street?  You may need to capture both to display it. Also 7 zip may be doing some terminal detection to know if it can keep updating the progress without scrolling the window.

Comment: Probably the `\r` carriage return that you're breaking when reading and printing stdout yourself. Do you have a specific reason why you do that? I.e., if you leave away `stdout` and `stderr` in the call to Popen, it should work. Otherwise, using `read` instead of `readline` and adding `end=""` to `print` might also work.